# Wordpress - Display Taxonomy Terms without Links - (get_terms, the_terms, wp_tag_cloud)

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

Is there a way to display Taxonomy Terms without them being a link?

I basically want to display all the terms underneath my Taxonomy of "Headings," but without them being links.

I've tried multiple solutions such as get_terms, get_the_terms, the_terms, wp_tag_cloud but I was unable to find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of *bizarre* returned all terms, if you need to display only the terms per post item you can use this:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy-term', array("fields" => "names") );
echo implode(', ',$terms);
```

Make sure to get the right "taxonomy-term" correct!

Answer (score 1):

below code retrieve all terms name of a taxonomy :

```
    $terms = get_terms( 'cars', array('fields'    => 'names'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_terms("taxonomy");
                 $count = count($terms);
                 if($count > 0)
                     {
                         echo '<ul>';
                         foreach ($terms as $term) 
                             {
                                 echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';
                             }
                         echo '</ul>';
                     }
```